# 'authenticate' missing from py2neo

Tags: py2neo

I have a smoothly running python project where I use the line

```
from py2neo import Node, Relationship, Graph, authenticate, cypher
```

However, when I moved the files to another machine and tried to run them there, it turned out that 'authenticate' couldn't be imported. And indeed, it doesn't show up under dir(py2neo) in terminal mode.

Python 2.7.13 on both machines. How can that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j_doc_manager/issues/76#issuecomment-446290239
You could try:

```
graph = Graph(host=HOST, auth=(USER, PASS))
```

and remove **authenticate** from import line